# ssl certificate for .ca and .com

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have a mail server which has a domain pointer with a .ca and .com (ie. mail.example.com and mail.example.ca).  Is it possible to have an SSL certificate for each for that mail server?  I am running Qmail with an Apache Web server front.  I tried to put the SSL pointer for the secondary extension in it, but that did not work.  So, currently it is only running for the .com extension (for SSL).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to have an SSL certificate for multiple domains.